# Is it safe to upgrade Jboss 4.0.5 quartz jars to Quartz 1.8.3?

Tags: jboss, quartz-scheduler

I would like to upgrade the quartz version from 1.5.3 which is on the jboss to the currently latest 1.8.3.

Testing it by replacing the old jar with the new and it's dependencies Jboss started just fine and I was even able to execute a scheduled job.

Should I be aware of any backward compatibility issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is probably fine. JBoss doesn't make heavy use of Quartz, I doubt it pushes the API particularly hard.

If it works for you, then go for it.

Comment: +1: I upgraded a JBoss 4.2.3 to quartz 1.8.4 without any issues, and I also had a go at updating to a 2.0.1 and it only took a few lines of client code to change (and some changes to the table schemas). So sticking to 1.8.x should be fairly easy for most versions, I assume.